# Drag'n'Drop into Electron app is not allowed

Tags: electron

I am trying to implement Drag'n'Drop functionality for users to easier upload their images. In browser the drop area works perfectly but Electron is preventing files to be even dropped into the app. Every time I try to drop a file cursor changes to the one shown below and nothing happens.

I thought maybe Electron had configs to disable dropping files by default due to popular complain but I couldn't find any solution.

[image]

The picture shows the drop area, but the same issue is all across the app.

Main.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

let win

function createWindow () {
  win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1000, height: 600, minWidth: 690, minHeight: 340 })

  win.loadFile('index.html')

  win.webContents.openDevTools()

  win.on('closed', () => {
    win = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Comment: @0.sh I don't really know what code you need to see. I added the code of main.js, the project is barebones so there isn't much to see. I recently started and this is the first issue I faced.

Comment: @Telion Are you just using the quick start app? What's in index.html/index.js?

Comment: @pushkin main.js is the same, yes. index.html is my html code with few js features from the demo app. I don't have index.js file at all. The thing is I tried removing every script from index.html already, that didn't help so I accuse electron of blocking drag'n'drop. If you need I could add the code of index.html too.

Comment: Could it be Windows fault? Because I face the same issue in demo and starting project too. I just realized it could be Windows too.

Comment: @Telion Where is the code that's showing the "Drag drop" text? Is that just an external page?

Comment: @Telion By the way, are you running the app as admin? Try not doing that.

Comment: @pushkin The code itself can be anywhere, it won't work either way since Every single time I have a file selected and try to drop it into Electron cursor changes into denying state and nothing works. I use `FilePond` library to work with droparea, it automatically replaces `<input type="file">` with the right code. Though I tried a couple of simple solutions that weren't working either, the issue is on another level so the code doesn't matter it seems like. I haven't compiled the app yet so I start it through npm: `npm start`, I don't know if it gives the app admin permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. That wasn't fun. Looks like something actually broke. But after I restarted the console, Windows then reinstalled the project, Electron, and NPM it finally worked. The problem is now solved.