# Native Drag and Drop File uploader using electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Im working on making a simple file uploader to upload jpeg files to a server. But I've hit a snag.

I cant seem to get the [Native File Drag and drop](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/native-file-drag-drop) to work. When ever I drag an image or any other file over to where the file uploader is, it just shows the stop cursor. Like so:

[image]

```
<input class="upload" type="file" id="Filedata" capture="" name="Filedata" multiple="" onchange="update()" accept="image/jpeg">
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         document.getElementById('Filedata').ondragstart = (event) => {
         event.preventDefault()
         ipcRenderer.send('ondragstart', '/path/to/item')
       }
       </script>
```

The above is my code that I am linking to. It worked fine on a Chrome test but it wont work correctly on the Electron app. What have I failed to do? Is there anything I'm missing. Ive place the other half of the code in my `main.js`

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('ondragstart', (event, filePath) => {
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: filePath,
    icon: '/path/to/icon.jpg'
  })
})
```

Anyone have any ideas as to what I've done wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is the [repo of my project](https://github.com/Arxhtects/Mock-Upload-App)

**EDIT**
Full reinstall has worked Thank you.

Comment: possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522702/dragndrop-into-electron-app-is-not-allowed)

Comment: After testing the above is accurate based on the answer that was provided. try re-installing. Possible duplicate of [Drag'n'Drop into Electron app is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54522702/dragndrop-into-electron-app-is-not-allowed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading the repo and testing I haven't seen any issues so it appears something was removed or changed by accident. There's two ways you could resolve this issue.

Option 1:

run `npm update electron-prebuilt -save` after reading "[Updating Electron](https://discuss.atom.io/t/updating-electron/24595)"

Option 2:

uninstall Electron and re-install with:

- uninstall: `npm uninstall electron`
- re-install: `npm install electron`

I did notice in your *main.js* that you've defined the constant `ipcMain` on line 34. It's a good practice to call constants at the top and you can modify:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
```

to:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')
```